# alert() in angularjs causes 5 messages instead one

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Probably it is "old school" using alerts when learn or debug JS, but sometimes I decline to such approach. I am learning angularjs, and it is very difficult to understand scheduling, I mean step by step how angularjs is executing different directives.
As an instance, here small app in angularjs, and I can not understand why on one alert there are 5 messages???

http://plnkr.co/edit/8j7D0J0a6By447whhpa3?p=preview

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

<style>

.red
  {
    color:red;
  }
</style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="demoApp">
    <div ng-controller="testCntr">
      <span ng-class="{red: setClass()}">Test color</span>
      <div>{{setClass()}}</div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',[]);

demoApp.controller('testCntr', function ($scope) {

  $scope.setClass = function () {
    alert('test');
    return true;
  }

});
```

Comment: That method is running each time the digest cycle runs.. look up info on the `$digest` cycle.

Comment: I have realized next issue:
2 alerts because of first digest cycle
2 alerts because of second (checking) digest cycle
1 alert - is very interesting???? Probably it is before first and second digest cycles, causing by "ng-class", what is necessary for HTML render
And also it seems depending on angular version (in 1.2.5 works expectable (1+2+2).).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're calling that function over and over again. Change it to be event driven and you'll be good:

http://plnkr.co/edit/zh0kIs?p=preview

html

```
<body ng-app="demoApp">

  <div ng-controller="testCntr">
    <span ng-class="{'red': changeClassModel}">Test color</span>
    <br><br>
    <button ng-click="setClass()">Hooray Alerts!</button>
  </div>

</body>
```

js:

```
demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',[]);

demoApp.controller('testCntr', function ($scope) {

  $scope.changeClassModel = false;

  $scope.setClass = function () {
    alert('test');
    $scope.changeClassModel = true;
    return true;
  }

});
```